# Get data out of buffers Typescript

Tags: angular, image, typescript, blob, buffer

So I have two buffers containing the binaries of an image each that I get from a database. I cannot figure out how to use the data! Nothing will let me extract it. I tried to cast in Uint8Array but it does not change anything.

I tried changing the buffers to Array when fetching them from the database, but the data comes in a string of character and when I try to encode the string, the output isn't right.

My goal is to get the data out of the buffers and make and two image.bmp out of them. I think I need to use Blob for that, but I haven't tried it yet.
If you have any idea of how to work with buffers, let me know.
I'm working in typescript with angular.

[image: Here a picture of the buffers when I console.log them]

Comment: Please post some minimal code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Textdecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) to create a String of the ArrayBuffer.

Example from doc:

```
let win1251decoder = new TextDecoder('windows-1251');
let bytes = new Uint8Array([207, 240, 232, 226, 229, 242, 44, 32, 236, 232, 240, 33]);
console.log(win1251decoder.decode(bytes)); // Привет, мир!
```